# Cómo ahorrar código en validaciones repetitivas

Tags: c#, .net, revisión-de-código

Tengo varios controladores que usan las mismas 3 validaciones en reiteradas ocasiones

Los endpoints requieren 3 cosas; el usuario que lo consume, el idioma y el recurso.

Las validaciones que se repiten en cada endpoint, básicamente son las siguientes:

```
var usuario = xxx.get(idUsuario)
if (usuario == null)
{
    return Unauthorized("mensaje de error")
}
var recurso = xxx.get(idRecurso)
if (recurso == null)
{
    return NotFound("mensaje de error")
}
if (string.isnullorempty(idioma) || !helper.isvalid(idioma))
{
    return BadRequest("mensaje de error")
}
var idiomaParseado = helper.parseidioma(idioma)
```

¿Existe alguna forma de que pueda hacer más eficiente este código? ¿Algún método para reutilizarlo?

Necesito las entidades y los mensajes de error.

Comment: idUsuario, idUsuario e idioma, son parametros de la función??? y xxx.get(idUsuario)?? que significa esas xxx??? es una función del controlador, de la clase o del context??

Comment: Siendo que los ifs contienen una sola instrucción, puedes quitar las llaves. Es lo mismo pero haces que el código sea más corto.

Answer (score 0):

Por tiempo de ejecución para qué sé unos milisegundos más rápido puedes cambiar:

```
string.String.IsNullOrEmpty(idioma)
```

por:

```
idioma==null || idioma==""
```

Debido a que falta información sobre las otras clases y métodos, y quieres devolver los tres errores. No veo ninguna otra mejora posible que no sea mirar los métodos que llama. Te aconsejo usar la clase **Stopwatch** para ver el tiempo de ejecución y así poder ver si lo reduces o lo aumentas y detectar cuál es el código que necesita optimizarse. Ejemplo del uso del **stopwatch**:

```
 var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        string idioma = "";
        watch.Start();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(idioma))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message error");
        }


        watch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Execution Time: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
         watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
         idioma = "";
        watch.Start();
        if (idioma==null || idioma=="" )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message error");
        }


        watch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Execution Time: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un controlador base y los tres controladores que dices podrían implementarlo y llamar a la misma función de este.

```
public abstract class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Validate(string idUsuario...) 
    {
        var usuario = xxx.get(idUsuario)
        if (usuario == null)
        {
            return Unauthorized("mensaje de error")
        }
        var recurso = xxx.get(idRecurso)
        if (recurso == null)
        {
           return NotFound("mensaje de error")
        }
        if (string.isnullorempty(idioma) || !helper.isvalid(idioma))
        {
           return BadRequest("mensaje de error")
        }
        var idiomaParseado = helper.parseidioma(idioma)
        return ...
    }
}

public class Child1Controller : MyBaseController 
{
    // Llamar al método base
    base.Validate(idUsuario...)
}

public class Child2Controller : MyBaseController 
{
    // Llamar al método base
    base.Validate(idUsuario...)
}
```

Comment: Buen día
Implementé lo que recomendaste y si bien al debuggear retorna el NotFound en MyBaseController, cuando ejecuto el endpoint no retorna el 400. El método retorna 400 pero sigue corriendo secuencialmente lo que viene después de ejecutar el método base.Validate()

Comment: Puedes controlar el resultado de la función padre (base) como cualquier otra que retorne un valor.. Entiendo que necesitarás algo como:

if (base.Validate(idUsuario...) != NotFound)
{
      Hacer algo...
}